# How to spread a tibble conbined with strsplit?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I need to spread a tibble where one column has many elements to split, and they're not the same length. I put the orginal sample and predicted outcome below. Thanks.

```
a;b;c | 2016
d;e  | 2019
```

converts it into:

```
a | 2016
b | 2016
c | 2016
d | 2019
e | 2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using `strsplit` and use `Map` with `data.frame` and `rbind` the result:

```
do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, a=strsplit(x$a, ";", TRUE), b=x$b))
#  a    b
#1 a 2016
#2 b 2016
#3 c 2016
#4 d 2019
#5 e 2019
```

or

```
y <- strsplit(x$a, ";", TRUE)
data.frame(a = unlist(y), b = rep(x$b, lengths(y)))
#  a    b
#1 a 2016
#2 b 2016
#3 c 2016
#4 d 2019
#5 e 2019
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c("a;b;c", "d;e"), b = c(2016, 2019))
```

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` solution

**sample data**

```
x <- data.frame(a = c("a;b;c", "d;e"), b = c(2016, 2019))
```

**code**

```
tidyr::separate_rows(x, a, sep = ";")
```

**output**

```
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   a         b
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a      2016
# 2 b      2016
# 3 c      2016
# 4 d      2019
# 5 e      2019
```

Comment: Thanks! It's useful. Maybe I should scan all the methods of the package to learn.